# Orientation change crashes my app

Tags: android

I have a class for constructing AlertDialog that contains spinner widget. When spinner shows its popup, if I change phone's orientation, my app crashes with exception saying something about leaked window. This matter has been discussed many times before, but only in the context of multithreading. But I have one thread. So what am I doing wrong?

```
public class ExpenseDialog extends DialogFragment
{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity());
    View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.expensedialog, null);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) content.findViewById(R.id.catspinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this.getActivity(), R.array.cats, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return  new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
        .setView(content)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
//some code
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
//some code
            }
        })
        .create();
}
```

}

I show the dialog like this:
(new ExpenseDialog()).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "expensedialog");

Comment: It's very large but it says at the beginnig: Activity andrey_it.expensetracker.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2aff8658 that was originally added here
02-21 19:39:56.174: E/WindowManager(19094): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity andrey_it.expensetracker.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2aff8658 that was originally added here

Comment: From what I've read it seams to me that I understand what causes error: after recreation of activity my popup happens to be linked with the previous activity that no longer exists. but what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report related to this: [Bug Report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4936)

Sorry, I can't help you to solve it --- I'm suffering from the same problem.

EDIT: Comment #7 worked for me. It didn't initially because I was using a DialogFragment and should have used onDestroyView() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link on `Handling Runtime Changes`, it will help you understand what needs to be done for orientation changes. When you change the orientation, you app is detroyed by `onDestroy()` and restarted with `onCreate()`, which can lead to issues.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: No, that's not the case here!

Answer (score 0):

try to add following attribute in manifest file of your activity from where you are showing this dialog...

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: This option is often abused and should not be a replacement for not doing your code homework. he must fix his leaking window, not override configuration changes.